# Permanently allow Chrome to access location

Tags: google-chrome, permission, preferences, geolocation

Recently, Google Chrome keeps loosing the ability to detect my location. When I open Google Maps, it has the icon indicating `This site has been blocked from accessing your location` and when I click it, a dialog containing `Location is turned off in Mac system preferences` is shown:

[image: Location is turned off in Mac system preferences, This site has been blocked from accessing your location]

So I have to go to `Enable Location Services`:

[image: Need to Enable Location Services for Google Chrome again]

But I am sure that I have done this several times recently. It seems that this setting is lost regularly (maybe for every Chrome auto-update?). How can I make this setting permanent?

Comment: What version of macOS are you on?  I have the same issue with Chrome 87.0.4280.141 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: Right now I am on macOS Big Sur version 11.2 and Chrome 89.0.4389.40, but I haven't had this problem for a while now (couple of weeks?), so it may have gone away.

Comment: I have the same problem and it annoys the hell out of me... I just updated to Chrome 89 and sure enough, had to enable it again. I'm beginning to think this is more of a Chrome than a Big Sur / MacOS thing...

Comment: Duplicate of: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408430/chromes-location-setting-constantly-disabled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is tracked [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1143807) (I think.) Sounds like it's fixed and hopefully will be corrected in a coming chrome version.

Answer (score 2):

This setting is permanent from the System's perspective, so this is a bug with Google Chrome. You're probably right that the auto-update process is causing problems.

You can try completely uninstalling Chrome and installing it, since that might fix some installation issue that was causing this to manifest.